# SQL runs very fast in PLSQL but very slow in Mybatis

Tags: sql, mybatis

I got a query SQL run very fast in PLSQL , but when running on project it becomes very very slow , almost 5-6 sec.  That makes a very slow response on my page.

in this project we use Mybatis ,and this SQL in mapper file just like others statements, in parameters —> java.lang.Long  ,  resulttype —> xxx.DTO, there’s one
more thing, this is a large SQL , it includes several   tags, each tag has it own bind parameter —>  #{partyId,TYPE=jdbc.DECIMAL}, but all the same in parameters PartyId.

when i graped SQL in log and put it in PLSQL, it runs very fast, only 0.47s.

I don’t know why.

Comment: Please show us the complete code of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us the SQL query which performs poorly on MyBatis? Are you using joins? I have made some queries much faster by dropping unneeded columns. Large result sets are handled quite slowly as MyBatis has to set all objects' fields individually.

Another strategy is to make for example two SQL queries instead of one very large one. In other words instead of joining everything together try removing one or two joins and "join" them using separate queries. It is worth trying to see how many joins are "OK" and at what point the execution time (with MyBatis or plain SQL console) gets too long. I've used this strategy successfully in many occasions.

Comment: ah thank you for your answer, it's really too large, and yes ,i use join .. on in SQL, and all columns is essential.

Comment: by the way, the column 'partyId' using index